# Java,Eclipse,JavaFX_ java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Hello StackOverFlowers.

I got stuck in using JavaFX

```
public class AppMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("root.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("This is title");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and here is my root.fxml file in same directory of above .java file

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">                                
    <padding>                                                           
        <Insets top="10" right="10" bottom="10" left="10"/>         
    </padding>                                                      
    <spacing>10</spacing>       
                                            
    <children>
        <TextField>
            <prefWidth>200</prefWidth>                                          
        </TextField>                                                            
    
        <Button>
            <text>Confime</text>            
        </Button>                                                           
    </children>                                                             
</HBox>
```

when I try to run the App
console shows me below messages..

[image: console View1]
[image: console View2]

I am very new in JavaFX...
I try to find what is problem with my code and what does this Exception means..
but I failed to find out what I want to know.

Is there anyone who got same message like mine and who knows whats going on on my code?

Thank you
and if there is more information that I need to offer for help my situation please let me know..
I will do all my best
Thanks again

Comment: Include `javafx.fxml` in your `--add-modules` argument, or make your code modular and add the necessary `requires` directive(s).

Comment: Thank you.!!!!Finally understood what I missed! Thank you so much Computer God will always bless and protect your code!

Comment: no screenshots of text, pleast - they are unsearchable and unreadable